# How to make my control bounce off screen edges?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store app. There are many draggable user controls (rectangles) in my app. If the user drags my control fast enough, the control will disappear. Otherwise, it will remain on the screen to prevent unwanted removes.

Now I know how to get the speed in `ManipulationDelta` event handler, but I don't know how to make my controls it bounce off screen edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of your problem can vary based on quite a few variables. For instance, do you want the boxes to rotate/collide with each other etc.

The most complete solution is to use a 3rd part solution such as Box2D (or its port for c# called [box2dx](http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/)). I am however not sure if there is a Win-RT version available.

Without using something like box2dx you'd have to roll your own physics engine. To do this you'd need to create a code loop that updates at a fixed interval (say 60Hz) and check the position and velocity of each rectangle at that point in time. If you could set up a loop like that then you could use [SUVAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) to calculate the position/velocity of each rectangle for the next frame.

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't need to detect collision, I've added a 'TranslateTransform' to my control and control its movement, but it's not so easy.